# 403 Forbidden for PHP on VirtualHost

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

When I am working from my root directory '/var/www/html' then index.php loads fine.

When I added a VirtualHost for my domain then I get the 403 Forbidden error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/dir
    DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/example/dir">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All the similiar issues regarding 403 Forbidden for php files discussed the 'Require all granted' option. 
I 'chowned' the directories to the apache user.
I don't know what else could cause it.

ls -la in directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jun 13 15:37 . drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jun 13 15:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache   21 Jun 13 15:37 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache   22 Jun 13 14:10 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache   22 Jun 13 14:07 info.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     10 Jun 13 15:04 test.html
```

Please help.
Yaron

Comment: Please edit the output of `ls -la /var/www/html/example/dir` into your question.

Comment: And please read the documentation [`Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html), especially the section `Access Control`. You are mixing the syntax of 2.2 and 2.4, which is explicitly discouraged. Use the 2.4 Notation only.

Comment: I have removed the 2.2 syntax but still get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I suggest that you check the `SELinux` labels on the Directory with `ls -lahZ` and also lock into the `SELinux` log file `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for any `denied` actions. This often happens when uploading and copying Directories within the Server.

Comment: Didn't see any 'denied' in the audit.log file.

Comment: What's in Apache's error log?